# Как убрать ссылку админ при отправке сайта в мессенджеры

Tags: веб-программирование, site

Когда я отправляю сайт например в Discord, то выходит ссылка admin и ниже нужная ссылка. Сайт написан на Wordpress. Как убрать эту ссылку?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Сам механизм дискорда, и других мессенджеров (вайбер, вацап, телеграмм и прочие) при вставке ссылки пытается вытащить со странице её заголовок, описание и картинку, в вашем случае эти данные определяются не так, как хотелось бы, значит нужно указать системе, какую информацию ей следует брать, почитайте к примеру [вот эту статью](https://mediaskunk.ru/2016/02/opengraph-messengers/).

Comment: Если совсем лень, то в самом ниху код который нужно вставить на сайт, в большинстве случаев этого достаточно, там буквально пару строк.

Comment: Спасибо за статью! Но у меня долбанный Discord выводит некую ссылку на админа. Как её можно скрыть вообще? https://yadi.sk/i/GRHiIpUrOm7UdA